# PowerMock issue when mocking a static method with Java7 construct

Tags: mockito, java-7, powermock, java-6, verifyerror

I am experiencing an issue with mocking a static test with my code compiled with **Java7**.

I am annotating my jUnit test with the annotations

```
 @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
 @PrepareForTest(StaticClassToMock.class)
```

When running my test and try to mock my static class with

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(StaticClassToMock.class);
```

it returns

```
java.lang.VerifyError: JVMVRFY012 stack shape inconsistent [...]
```

If in StaticClassToMock I remove the Java7 constructs by substituting the catched exceptions in OR and putting them in cascade it works fine.

I saw that the last version of Powemock (1.6.6) is compiled with Java6.

Is my issue related to the **Java7** constructs when PowerMock is compiled with **Java6**?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the thing with PowerMock - welcome to its bizarre errors.

First question would be - are you using an IBM JDK? Because IBM JDK and PowerMock go even more "bizarre" than Oracle/OpenJDK and PowerMock.

If you do some search, there are plenty of potential hints around:

1. [VerifyError on WAS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32821759/java-lang-verifyerror-jvmvrfy012-stack-shape-inconsistent)
2. [Code not working with Java7](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=7f616d94-a4ec-4e32-9ccc-3406ee063a6f)

Anyway, the first answer would be: simply try if running your JVM using *-noverify* makes any difference.

The longer answer: unless you are testing 3rd party code which you can't change; consider ... not using **static** code in a way that makes you turn to PowerMock.

You see, **static** is first of all an **abnormality** to good OO design. It should be used with great care; as it puts a lot of direct coupling into your code. And simply spoken: using **static** is a one of the simpl ways to create code that is hard/impossible to test! So, if changing your code is an option, you could watch those [videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD0011D00849E1B79) to learn how to create **testable** code in the first place. And then your need to turn to PowerMock ... will simply vanish.

My personal two cents: I have spent many hours hunting down such PowerMock problems. Then we decided to do different designs that only allows for **static** content that does not break our ordinary unit testing. Since then we are living fine with EasyMock and Mockito. No more need for PowerMock; no more need to spend hours on debugging problems that had **nothing** to do with our production code; but only the mocking framework.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation GhostCat, I perfectly agree about your points about static code and IBM JDK.
I am unfortunately extending IBM code and there is no way to modify the existing one.
Anyway I managed to solve this stuff: it was because of an oldjavassist library. Upgrading it to a newer one solved my issue. Thanks a lot!